# How to set width of jquery ui datepicker with multiple months

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

How can I set the width of the datepicker div when showing multiple months? 
I've tried changing the css for .ui-datepicker-group and .ui-datepicker-multi, but when I view it in Firebug the width is overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

For future people who will have the same question:

It is also possible to use the "max-width" property:

```
.ui-datepicker{
  max-width: 1024px;
}
```

You also can modify the font-size as Awais said, this is a good idea. 
The last possibility to play with the width is to use multi-columns months in datepicker JQuery UI configuration.

For instance:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [2,6] # 2: number of month per column, 6: number of columns
});
```

This will create 6 columns with 2 months by column, so you'll have 12 months perfectly displayed on two lines with the width correctly set.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me "max-width"

Answer (score 3):

```
div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:10px;
}
```

this will help you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to set the width. The width seems to be hard-coded to 51em. The best solution I've come up with is to tweek the font-size until I get the size I need.

Answer (score 2):

The best way of changing the width no matter what the CSS says is:

1. Find the js file that has datapicker (usually jquery.ui.datepicker.js)
2. Find

var origyearshtml,
    numMonths = this._getNumberOfMonths(inst) ...

1. Just under that or same line you'll notice width=17;
2. Change that to your preferred width.

this is the only solution that worked for me when using multiple months.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I have this script at the bottom, above closed body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){

        $(".ui-datepicker-inline").width("75em");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the jQuery UI datepicker javascript file and change the 'r' variable

```
_updateDatepicker: func...
...
r=17;
```

to the number EM width you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Save the `jquery-ui.js` in your development package, search for this

(inst.dpDiv.addClass('ui-datepicker-multi-' + cols).css('width', here set the width in px or em, remember the '' )

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $(".ui-datepicker-inline").width("75em");
});
```

that code works, but when the datepicker is modified, the `jquery-ui` update the width, so it only works on first load.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem; set the "min-width" to the (inline) container and groups.

Example:

```
.ui-datepicker-inline { min-width: 1848px; }
.ui-datepicker-group { min-width: 308px; }
```

The inline width styles would be overwritten by jQuery, but the global min-width value will overrule that width value.

Note: You can also use this trick to calculate your responsive size by javascript/jQuery. Setting the width to the container and group elements will not work; they will be overwritten when the datepicker is refreshing. So, create a style element and inject the css rules. jQuery snippet:

```js
var $myExampleCalendarParentContainer = jQuery('.your-selector-here');
var $style = $myExampleCalendarParentContainer.children('style');
var $calendarContainer = $myExampleCalendarParentContainer.find('.ui-datepicker-inline');
var $items = $calendarContainer.find('.ui-datepicker-group');
var monthWidth = 300; //desired pixel width per month

$style.html(
    '.ui-datepicker-inline { min-width:' + monthWidth * $items.length + 'px; }'
    + '.ui-datepicker-group { min-width:' + monthWidth + 'px; }'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You could of course set any width you want.

`.ui-datepicker-multi {width:100% !important}`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

```
  .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    visibility: hidden;
     width:100% !important;
}

 .ui-datepicker-group {width:100% !important}`
```